# typeahead fetch data from url key and api angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am new to Angularjs. I am trying to create a typeahead where I am fetching the data through the api. I tried searching for the solution but I dint get the solution what I was looking for. Below is the code what I have done so far.
HTML CODE:

```
<div ng-controller="newController">
    <div class="selection-box">
        <div class="title-box">
            <div class="search_item">
                <input name="document" ng-model='query' type="text" typeahead="document as document.name for document in documents | filter:query | limitTo:8" id='document' placeholder="SEARCH FOR YOUR DOCUMENT" class="search_box">
            </div>
            {{query}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this input box whatever I type it gets printed in the {{query}} but doesn't show any data fetching from the api. I am using bootstrap ui . Below is the controller what I wrote.

newController.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.service("searchService", function ($http) {
     var apiUrl = "http://12.56.677/api/v1/mobile/";
     var apiKey = "123nm";
     this.searchDocument = function(query) {
         var response = $http({
         method: 'post',
         url: apiUrl + "search",
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
         params: {
           key: apiKey,
           query: query
         }
      });
      return response;
    };
});

myApp.controller('newController', ['$scope', 'searchService' , function($scope, searchService, $rootScope, $http, $window, $document) {
    var apiUrl = "http://12.56.677/api/v1/mobile/";
    var apiKey = "123nm";
    url = apiUrl + "search";
    Key = apiKey;
    $scope.query  = undefined;
    console.log(query);
    searchService.searchDocument(query='').then (function (res) {
    if(res.data.status == "OK")
    {

        $scope.documents = res.data.result;
        console.log($scope.documents);
        // var userinformation = res.data.result;
        // $window.localStorageService.setItem('searchDocument',      JSON.stringify(query));
     }
     else {

         $scope.errorMessage = res.data.message;
     }
  })
 }])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `searchService.searchDocument(query='')` a typo? It looks for like a semantic error now. You are effectively calling searchDocument with an empty string

Comment: You are making the query only once,whereas it should happen everytime when you type something in your typeahead.

Comment: @kazenorin ok, so what shall i write instead of that. In console there is no error.

Comment: @MahendraSingh can you tell me how to implement that. I sorry I am so confused. I am just not getting how to fix

Comment: check through firebug tool, Is your request hit to server api ?

Comment: @Preety Singh You need to check your searchDocument's API for that

Answer (score 0):

```
  //HTML
  <input name="document" 
   ng-model='query' type="text" 
   uib-typeahead="document as document.name 
   for document in documents  |filter:query | limitTo:8" id='document' 
   placeholder="SEARCH FOR YOUR DOCUMENT" class="search_box">

  //Controller
  searchService.searchDocument('').then (function (res) {
    if(res.data.status == "OK"){
      $scope.documents = res.data.result;
    }
    else {
     $scope.errorMessage = res.data.message;
    }
  });
```

Comment: no sir but when I added the firebug extension in chrome It was showing some warning so I removed. But after that when I check it not showing anything in console

Comment: @PreetySingh Have you added ui-bootstrap-tpls.js to your html?

Comment: Yes sir added this  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
 in index.html

Comment: Can you check if the API request is being fired in the network tab?Or just add {{documents}} in your html and check if any data is present there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115681/discussion-between-preety-singh-and-mahendra-singh).

Answer (score 0):

What you attempted to do is using typeahead with a pre-fetched list (an with an empty query).

You probably want to do asynchronous search and would need a data fetch function to do so.

HTML, note the typeahead expression:

```
<input name="document" ng-model='query' type="text" 
       typeahead="document as document.name for document in (getDocuments() | limitTo:8)" 
       id='document' 
       placeholder="SEARCH FOR YOUR DOCUMENT" class="search_box">
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('newController', ['$scope', 'searchService' , function($scope, searchService, $rootScope, $http, $window, $document) {
    var apiUrl = "http://12.56.677/api/v1/mobile/";
    var apiKey = "123nm";

    // What are these two undeclared variables lying here around for?
    url = apiUrl + "search";
    Key = apiKey;

    $scope.getDocuments = function(query){
        searchService.searchDocument(query) // Check your API, I am not sure how you're API treats these parameters
            .then (function (res) {
                if(res.data.status == "OK")
                {
                    var documents = res.data.result;
                    console.log(documents);
                    return documents;
                }
                else {
                    $scope.errorMessage = res.data.message;
                    return [];
                }
            })
    }
}])
```

Comment: Do you have the API documentation for `searchDocument` ? What parameters does it take?

Comment: No sir Actually I don't have. I took this code from the previous project and modified a little bit in my code and I was trying to implement in my project. Is there any other way than using searchDocument.?

Comment: These are the params url = apiUrl + "search";
    Key = apiKey;  is it possible to use in the apiUrl like this:

var apiUrl = "http://12.56.677/api/v1/mobile/search";

Comment: You may want to look for the implementation for `searchService` in your project. Otherwise, you may want to use the $http service to directly request for it. I still have no idea how to use your `apiUrl` 's API. There can be many possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return promise from the searchService.searchDocment() as below:

```
return searchService.searchDocument(query='').then(......)
```